# Why am I missing design elements of Android Studio attributes tab?

Tags: android

I am currently learning to use Android studio by following video tutorials, newly installed on a new computer.

Some options do not exist in my attributes. However, when I put them in manually in the code tab they appear in the design tab as well.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av0tk.png)

[After adding manually (not sure I've even done this correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKEYg.png)

Am I missing something obvious here?